# How to log from an app included in Solr running in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, solr, logback

We are using a Tomcat 6.0.35 with a Solr 4.0.0. We placed some jar-files in lib directory in the instanceDir of our SolrCore.
In our jar's there are some classes which are using some intern logback configuration/classes.(A facade for the logging-framework (currently Logback/SLF4J). Support additional functinality,)
We can't make it work, that the logging of our jar's is working.

We tried:

1. Editing the default logging.properties. In this case, all the log belong to our logger, but contain the log statements of our application.
2. Giving the Solr a logback.xml file, with logback jars in the lib folder. In this case we havn't got any logs in our logfiles.
3. Making the tomcat using logback to log. In this case we recieved different logs from the tomcat and from other classes in the org.apache.catalina. There was no log from the Solr nor our application in the log files

What can we do to  we customize our logging?
We would like to use logback if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

At least it was enough to make the Solr using logback. Therefore we placed the logback-core and loback-classic jar file in the Solr's war file and gave a logback configuration file as a program parameter and disabled the Solr's standard logging. We don't think that this is the best solution but it worked.

- We unpacked the solr.war file:

  ```
  jar  xfv solr.war

  rm solr.war
  ```
- and then copied logback-core-.jar and logback-classic-.jar into the folder WEB-INF/lib

  ```
  cp /SOMEPATH/logback-core-<version>.jar /SOMEPATH/logback-classic-<version>.jar WEB-INF/lib
  ```
- at least we build the war file again

  ```
  jar cfv solr.war *
  ```

Now we adjusted the programs parameters:
We've set the following options in the instance.env file

```
export LOGGING_CONFIG="-Dnop"

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/SOMEPATH/logback.xml"
```

Then the Solr logged via logback as it was specified in logback.xml file. We received logs from our application in the Solr too.